# Restart TextView marquee animation

Tags: android, textview

Is it possible to start TextView's marquee animation over again when it's not repeated forever? Let's say user of my app stays on the same activity for some time and wants to recall ellipsized text when its animation has already ended (e.g. by clicking on it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `selected` property successively to `false` and `true` will make TextView restart the animation.

```
textView.setOnClickListener {
    it.apply {
        isSelected = false
        isSelected = true
    }
}
```